# How can the underworld nurture a relationship with the political elite?

Tags: government, politics, secret-society, criminal-underworld

I, John Gotti, am remembered as the greatest criminal Mastermind in American history. I became the head of La Costra Nostra, an underworld group of Italian businessmen who were unjustly prosecuted by our government. While we may not have always made an honest buck, our heroism was above reproach as we always looked out for communities and the little guy in society. We supplied hard-working Americans with liqour when the snobby do-gooders outlawed it, helped the government invade Italy to end facism during WW2, and contributed to an almost successful assassination of US enemy Fidel Castro. However, our patriotism was rewarded with treachery, as our own government betrayed us with the RICO laws, destroying our benevolent organization.

After some time-traveling shenanigans involving a purple giant and a magical guantlet, I have managed to go back in time to change history in our favor. I intend to ingratiate the mafia into governmental politics to protect us from treacherous leaders who would use us as scapegoats. This was tried in the 60s when we got JFK elected. However, he betrayed us when he hired his brother as attorney general and gave him the task of going after us. They used and threw us away, whicj forced to have them both killed, as all traitors should pay a harsh price.

I need a way to encourage cooperation between us and the government so that we become entangled with them, preventing double-crosses like this from happening. What could we have done differently to ensure this outcome ?

Comment: *blinks* What? Are you asking about the actual Mob could have done, or a generic underworld organization?

Comment: This...uh, is not entirely hypothetical. Have a look at basically all of politics. Ties with organised crime have existed and will exist. In some countries these are stronger than others and the criminals could be quite influential and thus out of reproach. And to be in politics you need strong connections. Connections that include the organised crime.

Comment: hell, look at the cartels in mexico. look at how much control they have, and how they control the politics, and put an idiot as the president of mexico @VLAZ.

Comment: Government's too big for this to happen. They'd need to effectively control both the executive and legislative branches... one or the other and you would have the un-co-opted branch go after government corruption. Congress can, for instance, refuse to appoint an Attorney General, or pass RICO laws. But if they're the co-opted branch, they can be gone after by the White House. Nor can you really attack it from the angle of political parties (they did that in reality, look where it got them). If this is a story, it's probably more interesting showing how these plans fail.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the American Mob has "The Comission" as it's head.   You may be on the Comission, but you're only one of 5-6 (maybe a few more) officials who decide things.  You're only the head of one family, not them all.

Second of all, you got to the Comission without greasing a few palms here and there?  The real mafia has always been invested in politics and the political machines of their preferred party.   For legitament political investment, give generous contributions from your own legitimant bank accounts to campaigns... Politicians are, from time to time, threatened with getting fired by their bosses (the voting masses).   Find the guys who you like and like you back.   And if they don't like you... well, come one he's a politician and you're the head of the mafia.  As far as sinners go, you're a minor league compared to his Babe Ruth.   Figure out his favorite vices, and then let them know you know about it... but you can keep a secret... Hell, if it's the right vice you know a guy who can help you discreetly.   And do you know how little cops are paid to hunt down bad guys... and how stressful their jobs are... finding all those water soaked bodies in the river cause people never learn that you shouldn't go swimming in the Hudson while wearing cement shoes?   They need something relaxing after a shift dealing with that.

And if you're time traveling... why not get your Johnny boy president back in line.  Chat up those secret service buds of his... tell'em your a reporter doing a piece on the President.   You just want to know the man... ask'em about the President's favorite movie stars... that's a good innocent conversation that will help the people get to know the real JFK...  And if Bobby-boy sends the FBI after you... just keep your cool while you talk to his goons.   I got a perfect technique that can get you though any G-man's shake down... think about his boss, Mr. Hoover, walking around in women's clothing.   Hell, let your FBI snoop in on the joke.  Come on, it's the 60s, no high level government man is gonna be into that kinda thing.

And hey, if Kennedy's betray still makes you seethe, it might be you have anger management issues on account of how hard your working.  I recommend you take up a hobby.  You know what's really relaxing?  Late Night Picture Taking.   Trust me you don't know relaxin' til you find yourself down a lonely dirt road on a hot July night when the rest of the town is sleepin' like babies.   Nothing like it in the world.   In fact, I'll let you in on the best secret.   Best place for late night picture taking is this little shallow lake in this small, quiet vacation town in Massechutes.  Place called Chappaquiddick.  Beautiful place.  Just you, your camera, and that quite lake sure on that amazing night.   Just keep clear of the dirt road.  No one really uses it at that hour of night... but the ones that do, they drive fast.  You don't want to fall in.

Just be careful... after all, when you think about it, what is a government but the country's most successful mafia outfit.

Answer (score 2):

The reasons why organized crime fails in places like late 20th century USA is that there are too many people in power, too much legal money for crime syndicates to become stronger than the government sponsored police forces, and too much patriotism to not get blindsided by the occasional do-gooder like JFK.  You can buy a few cops here and there, maybe control a few key politicians, you can even be the president himself, but as long as you are breaking the law as a matter of practice, you will eventually find yourself brought under heel.

**This leaves you with one obvious option:**

Don't do crime... Just joking, you'll still become rich and powerful doing something dishonest and illegal, but it will be the one illegal thing they absolutely can not bust you for: insider trading.  You are from the future, you know what major corporations are going to rise and fall long before they even begin to take shape.  You know when their stocks will be cheap and when they will explode.  With just a little investment capital left over from the moonshine days, you can maneuver yourself to be the majority shareholder of Amazon, Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Apple, and Odeo by buying them up while they are still in their infancy.

Antitrust do gooders might resist so much wealth and power being in one place, but no matter how hard they try to prove you are doing insider trading, they can never prove it because the only person who's actually feeding you this secrete intel is future you.   Moreover, your wealth will so single handedly drive the economy, that any attempt to go after you would be massively destabilizing to the nation making your existence the better evil.  A senator calls you out? Just threaten to outsource a few thousand jobs in his home state and see who backs down.

Also, your authority over mass media and technology will be so complete that no politician can run for office without your approval.  Every election will be rigged based on who you decide to censor. People vote in your underlings into every office conceivable because you make sure that their names are the only ones anyone hears.  All they see is Stefano-Democrat, Luigi-Republican, and a bunch of other names they never heard of before... sure America, enjoy your choice.